# Android ADT Eclipse Layout Editor giving StackOverflowErrors

Tags: android, android-layout

The layout editor is giving me StackOverflowErrors which ask me to exit eclipse everytime I load a layout XML.

this is clearly a bug, but does anyone know a workaround so I know what not to do? Unfortunately it's happening regardless of what layout I open.

I'm using Indigo with ADT v18

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.SubList$1.<init>(AbstractList.java:688)
    at java.util.SubList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:687)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:284)
    at java.util.SubList.iterator(AbstractList.java:678)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:162)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1027)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2334)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.findResValue(ResourceResolver.java:206)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceResolver.resolveResValue(ResourceResolver.java:333)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue report here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24317

It appears to be an issue with resource referencing. No solution found so far but this reminds me that the problem happens after I changed the theme of the app. So I changed it back and it's allright now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when building at 4.0.3 with actionbarsherlock.
After my USB SSD disconnected with Eclipse open, I got a stack overflow every time I tried to open any xml layouts in my project. Initially I could get around it by either changing by build target back to 2.3.3 and eventually discovered removing the actionbarsherlock application theme stopped the crashes.
I found the fix was to remove the actionbarsherlock library and import a fresh version. This completely fixed the issue.